# Default parentheses upon object destructuring

Tags: javascript, function, object, destructuring

I've recently run into a problem that I can't fix.

I'm writing some code where I have to access data with the help of an input range field. I want to write a getData function which looks like this:

```
function getData() {
  let currentValue = slider.value;
  let index = currentValue - 1;
  return { pageViews, monthlyCost, leftPercentage } = viewsData[index];
}
```

this works BUT everytime I save my file visual studio code adds a parenthesis around the destructuring assigment like this:

```
return ({ pageViews, monthlyCost, leftPercentage } = viewsData[index]);
```

and after that the code doesn't work

can somebody help me with fixing this behavior in my code editor?
thanks (:

Comment: I suspect that function isn't doing quite what you think it's doing, although from the question title *maybe* it is. What do you think it's doing?

Comment: What is your issue with the parentheses? They aren't necessary, it's true, because of the `return` (they would be otherwise), but... If they're bothering you, though, find out what part of it is doing that (it'll be either the default formatting or a plugin like Prettier) and see if it has an option for "only add parentheses around object destructuring when necessary" or similar.

Comment: Hey T.J. you where right, it had nothing to do with the parenthesis, I tried it again with the parenthesis and it worked. I think it had more to do with how i structured my code and not with the object destructuring itself..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have the `prettier` extension install in your IDE. To prevent this automatic behaviour for that specific line of code, you can use `prettier-ignore` and exclude the next line from formatting.

```
function getData() {
  let currentValue = slider.value;
  let index = currentValue - 1;

  // prettier-ignore
  return { pageViews, monthlyCost, leftPercentage } = viewsData[index];
}
```